# Concatenate 2 columns and pass to function SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a reporting query that I need to improve, and my SQL skills are pretty basic. It's running on SQL Server 2008.

The query calls the same function twice and passes two different columns to it.

```
Column1        Column2
;122;6363;     ;383;4747;
;4848;4747;    ;353;5869;

EG: dbo.fn_CheckAccess(value1, Column1) + dbo.fn_CheckAccess(value1, Column2)
```

This basically calls the function twice for the same row, increasing the query time.

I'd rather concatenate Column1 and Column2 and pass it to the function like this:

```
dbo.fn_CheckAccess(value1,(Column1 + Column2))
```

When I tried the above, the results do not match that of the original query with the separate function calls. When I concatenate the two Columns in a select statement, it displays what I want:

```
    select (Column1 + Column2) as TotalColumn

TotalColumn
;122;6363;;383;4747;
;4848;4747;;353;5869;
```

Somehow I can't seem to pass it correctly through to the function. What am I missing?

Edit: I was able to figure out that the issue was caused by the double semi-colon. It did not work with the function. So I had to trim it down to make it work.

Function code for reference:

```
    USE [DB_NAME]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

  CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_CheckAccess] ( @User VARCHAR(255), @AssigneeGroups VARCHAR(4000) ) RETURNS integer  AS 

  BEGIN DECLARE @Delim VARCHAR(1), @I INT, @J INT 
  DECLARE @GroupList VARCHAR(4000) 
  SET @Delim = ';' SET @I = 0 SET @J = 0 

  SELECT @GroupList = Group_List FROM user_x WHERE Login_Name=@User 
  IF PATINDEX('%;'''+@user+''';%',@AssigneeGroups) > 0 BEGIN RETURN 1 END 
  WHILE @I <= LEN(@GroupList) BEGIN SELECT @J = CHARINDEX(@Delim, @GroupList, @I) IF @J = 0 BEGIN SELECT @J = LEN(@GroupList) + 1 END  
  IF PATINDEX('%;'+substring(@GroupList, @i, @j - @i)+';%',@AssigneeGroups) > 0 BEGIN RETURN 1 BREAK END SELECT @I = @J + LEN(@Delim) END  RETURN 0 END

GO
```

Comment: you can use concat(column1, column2) function

Comment: CONCAT is not available for SQL Server 2008. I checked.

Comment: What is the logic inside your function? You may need to change that to accommodate concatenated values.

Comment: have you tried using coalesce? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: Change your function and add it another parameter and it retrive Column2 and do what you want in this function. and if you are consider on performance dont use function. There is always anohter way

Comment: COALESCE won't work, as I'm not concatenating rows, but columns. I think my issue here was with the ";;" double semicolons which messed with the function. I got better results when I replaced it with a single semi-colon.

Comment: I can't seem to add my function code to comments here. I don't have the option of changing anything related to the function as it's used with too many reports, so I have to figure workarounds.

Comment: Please post your function's code

Comment: @Andrea - query for reference: